# Simple Java program breaks when throwing exception

Tags: java, exception, runtimeexception

I have simple program with throwing exceptions, and I understand output I get, but not exception I get. 
Here is the code:

```
//Q1.java
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Q1{
  public static void main(String args[]){
    Q1 q1=new Q1();
    Q2 q2=new Q2();
    try{
      System.out.println(q2.method(q1));
      System.out.println(q2.method(q2));
    }catch(QE1 e){
      System.out.println("exception 1");
    }finally{
      System.out.println("finally");
    }
  }

  Object method(Q1 q) throws QE1{ 
    if(q instanceof Q1){
      System.out.println("method");
    }
    else {
      throw new QE2();
    }
    return 1;
  }
}

class Q2 extends Q1{

  Object method(Q1 q) throws QE1{
    if(errorCheck()&& q instanceof Q2){
      throw new QE2("error 2");
    }else if(q instanceof Q2){
      throw new QE1();
    }else{
      return new String("abc");
    }
  }

  boolean errorCheck(){
    return true; 
  }

}

class QE1 extends Throwable{
  public QE1(){
    System.out.println("qe1 - 1");
  }
  public QE1(String s){
    super(s);
    System.out.println("qe1 - 2");
  }
}

class QE2 extends RuntimeException {

  public QE2(){
    System.out.println("qe2 - 1");
  }
  public QE2(String s){
    this();
    System.out.println("qe2 - 2");
  }

}
```

Output is:

```
abc
qe2 - 1
qe2 - 2
finally
QE2
    at Q2.method(Q1.java:33)
    at Q1.main(Q1.java:10)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at edu.rice.cs.drjava.model.compiler.JavacCompiler.runCommand(JavacCompiler.java:272)
```

and then program breaks, but I am not sure why.
Problematic line is the one in constructor of QE2.
I kind of assume that, because QE2 is subclass of RuntimeException and for that reason, constructor of RuntimeException is called, so program breaks.
Is this the case or something else?

Comment: What do you mean with "breaks". Please add the stack trace you get! You see, this code is **probably on purpose** written to be hard to read. Do you really think this is good input for other people? You making it 10 times harder for us to help you; just because of this over-complicated code in there.

Comment: do you get a stacktrace at the command line? if so please show.

Comment: Also it might be helpful to give your class and method names something meaningful.  Calling it "Q1" and "Q2" and "method" will get you confused very quickly.  You can do what you want but this is bad practice imo.

Comment: Calm down everyone. I usually don't write code like this, confusing and uninformative. I am practicing for exam, and it *should* be confusing.
Also, I added stack trace.

Comment: I cannot be certain more... I ran code more then few times, and output is the same. Why do you think it should be like that?

Comment: @misty I gave you an answer below.  There is nothing unexpected happening in your code, as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing unexpected about the output/behavior of your code.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Q1 q1 = new Q1();
    Q2 q2 = new Q2();
    try {
        // this prints "abc" and no exception is thrown
        System.out.println(q2.method(q1));

        // this throws a new QE2(), which prints
        // this prints "qe2 - 1" followed by "qe2 - 2"
        System.out.println(q2.method(q2));
    } catch(QE1 e) {
        System.out.println("exception 1");
    } finally {
        // your code ends up here, which prints "finally"
        System.out.println("finally");
    }
}
```

You are throwing an exception of type `QE2` in the `try` block of your `main` method.  However, you never actually catch that type of exception, since you only catch `QE1`.  As a result, you end up in the `finally` block, which prints `"finally"`.

If you want to catch all exceptions, then you can use `catch (Exception e)` right before the `finally` block.

Comment: I understand what program prints. But why do I get exception?

Comment: You _throw_ an exception of type `QE2`, but you do not catch it.  What do you think throwing an exception means?

Comment: Yeah, I get it know. Thank you very much!
One thing left confusing is this: shouldn't catch block with `QE1` catch *all* exceptions, since it is subclass of Throwable?

Comment: @misty `QE1` is a subclass of `Throwable`, but not a subclass of `Exception`, so this is why `QE2`, is not caught.

Comment: It is confusing for me because if there was `catch(Throwable e)`, `QE2` would be caught...

Comment: Yes, because both `QE1` and `QE2` derive from `Throwable`, but they _don't_ both derive from `Exception`.